# Disable Umbraco aspx handling

Tags: umbraco

I have a project where I want to use Umbraco only for the backend as a CMS. But I want to disable it completely in the frontend handling my aspx pages for me, and I want to use the API to get the content I want. In other words, I want to create an aspx page manually which will not be handled by the Umbraco engine. Right now, if e.g. you create a test.aspx page and put it in the root folder, it will return 404 because Umbraco will look for a node with this alias.

Ho do I disable the .aspx handling by Umbraco, but still be able to use Nodefactory etc. in codebehind to access the content?

Thanks

Themos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few ways you can override pages so that their URLs are not "caught" by Umbraco, you can do this by modifying the following `appSettings` items in the web.config file.

**To add single files:**

```xml
<add key="umbracoReservedUrls" value="~/myfile.aspx,~/config/splashes/booting.aspx,~/install/default.aspx,~/config/splashes/noNodes.aspx" />
```

**To add whole subdirectories:**

```xml
<add key="umbracoReservedPaths" value="~/myfolder,~/umbraco,~/install/" />
```

You should be able to add `~/` to `umbracoReservedPaths` which would disable all URL mappings, I just tried it and it seemed to work. But I can't vouch that it'll have no unintended side-effects on the running of the Umbraco CMS.